# Query to get rid of matching records C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

I want to be able to write a query in C# Visual Studio 2012 in a WinForms Application that won't display matching records. Say I have a record in an Access DB that reads,

```
JOHN SMITH MALE   19
JANE DOE   FEMALE 19
JOHN SMITH MALE   19
```

And a query something like this

```
SELECT a.NAME FROM [NAME] a WHERE a.NAME = JOHN SMITH 
//but returns both records in the table
```

How would I be able to just return one single record from the table? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you have a primary key on your table?

Comment: Try to use sub query with NOT IN statment. http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property

Comment: No offense, Stick, but in the past week you've asked some REALLY basic SQL questions.  You may want to go out and buy a "SQL For Dummies" book or something (NOT implying you're a dummy, but obviously you need a book that adresses basic SQL questions).  De-duping a dataset is about as basic as it gets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this directly in SQL.
Use `distinct` to get only records that are no duplicates

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.NAME 
FROM your_table a 
WHERE a.NAME = 'JOHN SMITH'
```

or use  `top` to get only a certain amount or records as result

```
SELECT top 1 a.NAME 
FROM your_table a 
WHERE a.NAME = 'JOHN SMITH'
```

Comment: And I recommend to do this directly in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to modify the query you supplied so that instead of returning

```
John Smith
John Smith
```

it only returns

```
John Smith
```

?
If that is the case then you want

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.NAME FROM [NAME] a WHERE a.NAME = "JOHN SMITH"
```

If this isn't what you wanted to do, then maybe you could update your question to better explain your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't quite clear if you want to do this in C# or SQL. Juergen's answer is good.

If you're using, or at some point decide to use LINQ in C#, there's a FirstOrDefault() option when getting one row, like so:

```
return db.NameTable.Where(q => q.name == "John Smith").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -3):

Use Group By in your sql statement [reference removed 'cause of bad karma] or distinct [reference removed 'cause of bad karma]

Comment: Disclaimer: I haven't downvoted you, but we generally consider w3schools to be [a bad resource](http://www.w3fools.com/). Additionally, better answers include code examples as well as links to external resources.

Comment: jajaja OK. I know that a lot of people have a conflict because w3cschool are not affiliated with the w3c; no problemo... good to know that...